# Need help implementing a scrollbar on multiple views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, interface-builder

Okay so I'm new to this and have been trying to find a solution with no avail. I want to add a scroll bar to several pages of an app but when I add the outlet it doesn't show up on the side so I can link the 2. The only page it shows up on is the default view in storyboard.

In viewcontroller.h I have.

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;

}
```

and in viewcontroller.m I have...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

now when I make another view controller the outlet on the right side of the screen that I can link it to isn't there. What would I need to do to link a outlet to the scrollbar? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I must say I don't quite understand what you are doing, but maybe that's just me .. ?! besides that, variables always start with a lower-case character!

Comment: The UIScrollView would always be a subview inside any UIViewController you instantiate. So if you're trying to create a new view controller named MyNewViewController, you'd also give it a UIScrollView. But I'm not sure that's what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbars are added to appropriate controls automatically when their contents exceed their on-screen real estate. I think you're trying to add something that is an inherent feature of the operating system.

To what do you wish to add a scroll bar?

Also, you're instantiating a UIScrollView, which is a specialized subclass of UIView. It is specialized precisely to handle scrolling for content larger than the on-screen view port (as I mentioned above).